# Laravel Custom Error Validation JSON Response Object to Array

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I try to create an API for the registration form if a user does not fill the required field. The validator show error in object format but `i` need json response in an array format.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
    'name' => 'required', 
    'mobile' => 'required', 
    'address' => 'required', 
]);
if ($validator->fails()) { 
    return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);            
}
```

> Current output is

```
 {
    "error": {
        "name": [
            "The name field is required."
        ],
        "mobile": [
            "The mobile field is required."
        ],
        "address": [
            "The addressfield is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

> Expected output

```
{
  "error": [
      "The name field is required.",
      "The mobile field is required.",
      "The address field is required."
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the issue in accessing the Current output you get?

Comment: did you finally find a solution?

Comment: i found a solution and posted it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer is this one:

```
$err = array();

        foreach ($validator->errors()->toArray() as $error)  {
            foreach($error as $sub_error){
                array_push($err, $sub_error);
            }
        }
        return ['errors'=>$err];
```

the inner foreach is added because maybe more than one validation condition fails for an input( like : password is `too short` & `too weak`).

and Mayank Pandeyz's answer `for` loop won't iterate because until we add `toArray()` to the end of `$validator->errors()`.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the expected result, iterate the `$validator->errors()` using `foreach()` loop and push all the values in an array and return that array like:

```
$err = array();
foreach ($validator->errors() as $error)
{
    array_push($err, $error);
}

return response()->json(['error'=>$err], 401);
```